# Convert a Jsp with css to pdf

Tags: java, css, jsp, pdf, filter

I'm trying to convert a jsp with his css on a pdf (who should look the same).

First, I created a filter to take my html code.

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        ServletResponse newResponse = response;

        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            newResponse = new CharResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response);
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, newResponse);

        if (newResponse instanceof CharResponseWrapper) {
            String text = newResponse.toString();
            if (text != null) {
                response.getWriter().write(text);
                System.out.println(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do have a code of my jsp but not my css. I split my header and footer, that why I do not have my css.
How from that can I get a full design pdf?
Am I totally wrong, or it's a good start ?
Thx a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could then feed the intercepted response you have captured inside the filter to 'flying sacuer'. It's a framework for generating pdf from xhtml + css.

https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/

Comment: hi, I try to make it work but I'm kind of lost. I coudnt find simple exemple on YaHPConverter or flying-saucer