# Generate PDF with XHTML from processed JSP

Tags: jsp, pdf, struts-1, flying-saucer

related to [Convert a Jsp with css to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609502/convert-a-jsp-with-css-to-pdf)

Using flying-saucer, I can convert HTML/XHTML easily to PDF.

Now I want to be able to set parameters for the HTML/XHTML so I decided to use  a JSP for templating with core JSTL. Tomcat parse the JSP to HTML so I want to fetch the result to convert it to PDF by fetching the response content and process it through Flying-saucer.

However I don't know how to intercept the response content as related to the question above.

1 - ServletResponse interface seems to be useful for adding content before processing the JSP.

2 - HttpServletResponse is to modify headers of the response.

How can I fetch the content of the response inside my method, to process it with flying-saucer and then send it back to the client as "application/pdf" ?

N.B. : we are using Struts 1, I know it is bad, we are planning to move to Spring soon but not yet for this application.

---

Not-the-best-but-working solution :

For now I will use request parameters to set the content of the Jsp through URI, then send it back as "application/pdf" to the client.

```
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.CharArrayWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * PdfConverter
 * Pdf methods to convert Jsp from URI, or Xhtml/Xml from URI 
 * or internal content to Pdf.
 */
public class PdfConverter {

    private static String encoding = "UTF-8";

    /**
     * Convert JSP from local server to PDF
     * @param jspUri usage :
     *    URL jspUri = 
     *        new URL("http://localhost:8080/myApp/myJspServlet?param1=1&param2=2");
     * @param pdfFileName
     * @return Html content as a String from generated Jsp.
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static String JspToHtmlString(URL jspUri) throws DocumentException, 
                                                            IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(jspUri.openStream())
        );
        CharArrayWriter caw = new CharArrayWriter();
        int octet = 0;
        while ((octet = in.read()) != -1) { caw.write(octet); }
        String pdfContent = caw.toString();
        caw.close();
        return pdfContent;
    }

    /**
     * Convert Xhtml from package to PDF to the folder where this class is 
     * located.
     * @param xhtmlFileName name of the Xhtml file inside the application.
     * @param pdfFileName name of the written Pdf file.
     * @return Pdf file generated and written on disk.
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static File XhtmlToPdfConverter( String xhtmlFileName, 
                                            String pdfFileName) throws
                                                             DocumentException,
                                                             IOException {
        FileOutputStream pdf = new FileOutputStream(pdfFileName);
        new ITextRenderer() {{
            setDocumentFromString(
                new Scanner(
                    this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(xhtmlFileName), encoding
                ).useDelimiter("\\A").next()
            );
            layout();
            createPDF(pdf);
        }};
        pdf.close();
        return new File(pdfFileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can wrap request. See [struts2-pdfstream](https://github.com/aleksandr-m/struts2-pdfstream) for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually invoke a request dispatcher to render a view. This is a Spring implementation but the idea and most of the classes should be the same.

For this to work you must somehow get your `ServletContext` then render the view using a fake request/response

```
// the request url and method arent really relevant, they could be if we wanted to use that information but were not
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest(servletContext, "GET", "/arbitrary/url");
MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

addModelAsRequestAttributes(request, modelMap);


LocaleResolver localeResolver = new JspLocaleResolver();
localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, Locale.getDefault());
// Push our LocaleResolver into the request
request.setAttribute(DispatcherServlet.LOCALE_RESOLVER_ATTRIBUTE, localeResolver);          

// Push our Locale into the request
LocalizationContext localizationContext = new LocalizationContext(null, Locale.getDefault());
request.setAttribute(Config.FMT_LOCALIZATION_CONTEXT+".request", localizationContext);
request.setAttribute(Config.FMT_LOCALE, Locale.getDefault());

servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/pdf_views/mypage.jsp").include(request, response);


return response.getContentAsString();



/*
 * Moves the items in the map to be request.attributes
 */
private void addModelAsRequestAttributes(ServletRequest request, Map<String,Object> modelMap) {
    if(modelMap != null && request != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : modelMap.entrySet()) {
            String modelName = entry.getKey();
            Object modelValue = entry.getValue();
            if(modelValue != null) {
                request.setAttribute(modelName, modelValue);
            } else {
                request.removeAttribute(modelName);
            }               
        }
    }
}
```